# How to get and use unknown class

Tags: c#

I want to receive `ObservableCollection<T>` where `T` is unknow. (I'm making like a library, so I don't know what class is assigned)

The hole story like this.

1) I offer a property named `Prop` and coder assign `ObservableCollection<T>` to `Prop` like following

```
Prop = ObservableCollection<T>;  // where T is class which coder defined
```

2) Then I receive `Prop` and get information use reflection's methods (eg. GetProperties, GetType, FullName so on..)

Here, I don't know how to design the property `Prop`

I've designed it as

```
ObservableCollection<object> prop;

public ObservableCollection<object> Prop 
{
    set
    {
        prop = value;
        // here, I'll make process like 
        // value.GetType().GetProperties() etc.
    }
    get
    {
        return prop;
    }
}
```

But as you know if I assign `ObservableCollection<TestClass> test = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();` to `Prop`, a error occurred that

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Colletions.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<TestClass>' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<object>'`

If you let me know how, it will be pleasure

Comment: Why not design it as ObservableCollection<T>, instead of ObservableCollection<object> ?

Comment: could you add the stripped down class (class definition and the prop you want to build)?

Comment: you may create interface with property

Comment: Keep your property as object and cast to what you want after getting type with reflection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need a class with generic definition:

```
class TestGeneric<T>
{
    private ObservableCollection<T> _prop;

    public ObservableCollection<T> Prop
    {
        get
        {
            return _prop;
        }
        set
        {
            _prop = value;
            // here, I'll make process like 
            // value.GetType().GetProperties() etc.
        }
    }
}

class TestClass
{ }
```

so that you can use generic property:

```
        var generic = new TestGeneric<TestClass>();
        generic.Prop = new ObservableCollection<TestClass>();
```

Comment: thats the right answer, anyways, to save some real-estate i'd go for an autoproperty, since there is no processing in the getter/setter ;)

Comment: well, @wallah said they want some processing in the setter so I left their comments as they are

Comment: @BobDust thank you for answer! I can't understand directly since I only have learned C# two months by myself. It means Im study your answer :) Thank you!!